# Android Server response special chars ��������������V*�I

Tags: android, ssl, server, certificate, response

I got a problem with my Android response. I checked every step with this server and I can't get a solution. Here is detailed info:

**URL:** https://XXX/public/api/versions/published/2/1408
**METHOD:** GET

**Request header:**

```
Status  Complete
Response Code   200 OK
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
SSL TLSv1.2 (TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
Method  GET
Kept Alive  No
Content-Type    application/json
```

**Header response:**

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: okhttp/3.4.2
```

**Expected response:**

```
{
    "platform": "Android",
    "number": "5.5.3",
    "force_update": false
}
```

**Android received response:**

```
05-16 14:09:40.500 12368-12425/com.screens D/OkHttp: --> GET https://XXX/public/api/versions/published/2/1408 http/1.1
05-16 14:09:40.500 12368-12425/com.screens D/OkHttp: --> END GET
05-16 14:09:40.700 12368-12425/com.screens W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value ��������������Kn� of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**Server ssl_protocols:**
TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

**Server charset:** 
UTF-8

**Android Http client library:**
Retrofit 2.3.0

Comment: You're probably using the wrong encoding.

Comment: `and accept all Certs` You have no security whatsoever.  **Don't do that!**

Comment: Where? In my server or in my app? @SLaks "and accept all Certs" -> only for tests :( and nothing

Comment: Either.  You need to use the same encoding (which should almost always be UTF8) at both ends.  You need to learn how Unicode encodings work.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: @SLaks No, don't is an encoding problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a Gziped response, and your app is not being able to parse it.

Make sure that a gziped response is supported in the app.